# Python multiple treeviews

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I am trying to make a GUI using tkinter. How can i have 3 treeviews - two on the top side by side and third on the bottom below the two treeviews on the top. I managed to get 2 side by side. I provided the side value as left for the first two but when I use bottom for the third it comes in the middle of the previous two treeviews.

```
container = ttk.Frame()
container.pack(fill='both', expand=True, side=side)
self.tree = ttk.Treeview()
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you put upper-left and upper-right tree view widget, pack with `side=LEFT` to make them packed from `left` to `right`. (You can also use `side=RIGHT` if you pack right one first).

Beside that, pack from top to bottom. (pack with `side=TOP` or omit `side`)

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

# In Python 3.x
#from tkinter import *
#from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

upper_container = Frame(root)
upper_container.pack()

left_tree = ttk.Treeview(upper_container)
left_tree.pack(side=LEFT)
right_tree = ttk.Treeview(upper_container)
right_tree.pack(side=LEFT)

lower_tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
lower_tree.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

updated version that will allow user to resize upper / lower area using [`PanedWindow`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/panedwindow.htm).

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

# In Python 3.x
#from tkinter import *
#from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

pane = PanedWindow(orient=VERTICAL)
pane.pack()

upper_container = Frame(pane)
upper_container.pack()

left_tree = ttk.Treeview(upper_container)
left_tree.pack(side=LEFT)
right_tree = ttk.Treeview(upper_container)
right_tree.pack(side=LEFT)

lower_tree = ttk.Treeview(pane)
lower_tree.pack()

pane.add(upper_container)
pane.add(lower_tree)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Just one more thing. How can I make it such that we can manually resize each individual treeviews on the GUI.

Comment: @PottaPitot, Sorry, I don't know about it. How about search question or post a separated question?